Complex validation iteration process to check the count of records in ADF
Snowflake migration project - Teradata -> extract files -> ADLS(BLOB) -> Snowflake through ADF.
Extracted files are placed in some XYZ container as batches (each has some number of files ie 100). Ex. Batch1 to Batch10 folders, each has 50 data files (header and some records in each files) and 50 respective control files ( it has one row with filename record count of that particular data file).
In Batch1 folder -> has files like abc_date.csv.gz, abc_date.ctl, ijk_date.csv.gz, ijk_date.ctl,....
Now we need to do pre-validation if the counts are matching between data file and it's respective ctl file then we can proceed data loading to Snowflake. abc.csv.gz has 1(header)+100 records and abc.ctl has abc(filename) 100 date in one row.
How to achieve this validation in ADF? It has to go in iteration till batch 10 of all the files.
Tried to use Get Metadata to get the file list. Then inside for each, I wasn't able to achieve this logic. Can somebody help this

In ADF, currently it's not possible to read the number of rows of .gz file and also not possible to get the data from a .ctl file because only Binary datasets supports both these kinds of files.
To achieve your requirement, you need to convert the .gz file and .ctl file to csv files and then you can check the row count and file data. So, first convert and store the csv files in a temporary container in ADLS which you can delete it later.
To convert .gz which is in the subfolder to a csv file, use Binary datasets for the source and target.
Create dataset parameters in the source dataset.

Give those for the foldername and filename in the dataset like below and also select .gz as compression type in the source.

In the sink dataset also, create parameter for the filename. Here, don't select any compression type.

When you give these datasets to the copy activity, it will ask the parameter values here.

For the .ctl file conversion also, you need to create the same kind of datasets but don't give any compression type in the source dataset.
You can provide the values for the above parameters by following the below pipeline design.
Here you need to two pipelines (Parent and child) as it involves nested iterations for the Batch folders and its files.
Follow the below pipeline design:
Parent pipeline
- Get meta data activity1 -> Get the child batch folder names list (Batch1,Batch2,..)

- For-Each1 -> Give Get meta data activity1 child items array

    - Get meta data activity2 -> Use dataset parameter for the folder name and give @item().name for that in the activity. Get all the child items files list in each Batch folder. 

    - Filter activity1 -> Give Get meta data activity2 child items array as Items and in the condition give @endswith(item().name,'.ctl')

    - Execute pipeline (Child pipeline) -> Pass the filter activity1 output array to this as an array parameter File_names and also pass @item().name (Current Batch folder name) as string parameter folder_name.

        Child pipeline
        - For-Each2 -> Give the array parameter to this.

            - Copy activity1 -> Use Binary dataset and create parameters for the folder name, file name and select .gz as Compression type. Give this to the copy actiivty source. Give pipeline parameter folder_name, @concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'.csv.gz') in the pipeline to the dataset parameters respectively. Use a temporary location to copy this and that dataset should also be a binary dataset with a parameter for the filename. Give @concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'.csv') to this parameter in the copy activity sink. This will generate a csv file <filename>.csv in the temporary location by which we can get the file count. Refer to the process that I have shared above.

            - Copy activity2 -> This is to convert the .ctl file into a csv file. Create two Binary datasets with same parameters like above but the compression type should be empty in the source Binary dataset. Give the folder_name parameter and @item().name to the folder and filename parameters respectively for the source Binary dataset. In the sink binary dataset, give @concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'_ctl','.csv') to the filename parameter. This sink binary dataset should also be a temporary location.

            - Lookup1 -> Create a delimited txt dataset for the original csv file which is in temporary location. Create a dataset parameter for the file name and give the @concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'.csv') as value for that in the lookup activity. Uncheck the firstRow in the lookup activity and this will give count of the file in its output. You can acess it usinh expression like @activity('Lookup1').output.count

            - Lookup2 -> Create another delimited txt dataset for the ctl csv file which is in same temporary location and create parameter for the filename as same like above. Give the @concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'_ctl','.csv') as value for that in lookup and here select the FirstRow in it. This will give the first row value which contains the file row count in its output. You can access it using this expression  like @activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.<column_name>.

            - If activity1 -> Check the two counts are same or not using above expressions.

            - True activities -> Here, proceed with your activities to copy the .gz file or .csv file in temporary location to your target.

            - False activities -> Optional but if you want you can add any activities when row counts are not same.

(OR) You can use any programming logic for the validation. You can use function apps or databricks for that. Call these from ADF to validate and after validation, you can use ADF to copy to your target.

First you need to create two parameters in the child pipeline. One is of array type and anothe is of string type. Now, in the parent pipeline, inside For-Each, use an execute pipeline activity and connect it to the child pipeline. pass the filter activity output array to array parameter and @item().name to the string parameter. Here @item().name means the current Batch folder. Then follow the next steps.

am not able to achieve/get the array of (Pass the filter activity1 output array to this as an array parameter File_names) even after giving the datatype as array.

After creating required parameters in the child pipeline, come to the parent pipeline and after the filter activity inside for-each. create an Execute pipeline activity and add child pipeline name to it. Go to the parameters section in this execute pipeline activity, In that you can see the parameters of the child pipeline. Here, you need to pass the filter activity output array @activity('Filter').output.value to the array parameter and @item().name to the string parameter.

Great..Thank you.. I got it... But again we have issue in the lookup activity (in which we get the data file count).. since lookup activity has limitations in reading the huge volume of rows.. how to proceed this? am getting an error saying lookup activity exceeds limitation.

In that case, using dataflow is the only option instead of lookup activity. Use dataflow and use dataset parameters for that as well just like lookup. In the dataflow, first use a derived column and create a col1 with value common, then use surrogate Key transformation key1 and increment it by 1. Next, use aggregate transformation with GroupBy on col1 and in aggregate section create a column count with expression max(key1). Next, to export this data to the ADF pipeline, use Dataflow sink cache.

In the pipeline, get the required column count from the Dataflow activity by using the expression like @activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value. This expression gives an array, you need to look at this array and change the expression as per the count object column inside the array.

So, for getting count, instead of lookup, we are using dataflow. Go through this documentation and check all the required transformations to get a better idea about the dataflow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview.
